# Magento multi language rewrites SEO fix?

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have made a website in with Magento in one language 2 years ago and now I would like to add another language.
My actual structure is like that

- example.com/category/
- example.com/about.html
- example.com/product.html

and I would like to obtain a structure like this:

- example.com/lang1/category/
- example.com/lang1/about.html
- example.com/lang1/product.html
- example.com/lang2/category/
- example.com/lang2/about.html
- example.com/lang2/product.html

This is not a big deal since Magento allowes me us to do that simply logging in the backend ->System -> Configuration -> Web -> Add store code to Urls (YES)

I can't do this setting right now because before that I need to fix and do rewrites from the first structure to the new one.

- example.com/everything_without_the_/lang1/_path to a permanent
- example.com/lang1/everything

I need for example that the urls from the backlinks from posts from the socials and other webistes won't get a 404 error but will automatically be redirected with a 301 redirection to the equivalent page in the new structure.

So I would like to add a script like this in the natural language:

```
rewrite permanently all the urls which ends not with /lang1/ or /lang2/ to urls with the prefix /lang1/
```

I know that I could manually add rewrite rules with this schema in the Magento backend but I would prefer to know if it is possible to batch this directly from the database or with some script in the .htaccess or index.php and above all which one between these solutions will have a less negative impact in SEO and SERP.

---

I've found a solution

Hi I've found a solution:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.)?example.com$ [NC] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/it/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /it/$1  [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.)?example.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ it/index.php [L]
```

at a first look works, but I not guarantee. 
I hope this will help
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution

Hi I've found a solution:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.)?example.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/it/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /it/$1  [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ it/index.php [L]
```

at a first look works, but I not guarantee. I hope this will help Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/lang1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/lang2/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1/lang1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use .htaccess 301 url to make if possible with your own `regex function`

As you need some specific requirement to do with your language part

here i am giving you category example

**Redirecting Subcategory URL with New Parent URL**

Examples:

```
category/sub1 redirect to cat/sub1
category/sub2 redirect to cat/sub2
category/sub3 redirect to cat/sub3
```

This may be needed if you changed a parent Category URL or even if you want to remove the parent URL completely:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*) http://www.yourwebsite.com/cat/$1 [R=301, L]
```

OR to remove `'/category/'` completely from `yourwebsite.com/category/sub` and end up with `yourwebsite.com/sub` ('sub' can be any url):

RewriteRule ^category/(.*) http://www.yourwebsite.com/$1/ [R=301, L]

And also you can refer

http://www.learnmagento.org/magento-tutorials/301-redirects-in-magento/

http://blog.maximusbusiness.com/2012/10/magento-url-rewriting-regex-and-301-redirects-tips/

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Thanks Liyakat for your input, my problem is exactly the opposite of the example because I need to add the new language code between example.com and all the sub-pages. Probably this can be reduced to your example. Let's say /it/ is the path to add to all the pages which not ends with /en/ /it/ an be right this? `Rewriterule $.com/(.![it|en])   http://example.com/it/ [R=302, L]`

Comment: you should have to little search for regex. and with help of you can sure achieve this

Comment: @eliosolutions,pls dont forget to acpt.if i could help u